# Broad / Depth or Breadth / Depth?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, adjectives

I recently saw this image:

https://www.google.pl/search?tbm=isch&tbs=simg:CAQSHQkY_1wo-9gUZnBoSCxCwjKcIGgAMCxCOrv4IGgAM

(in context of personal skills, T-shaped set of copetencies, if that is of importance).

What struck me is the use of "broad + depth" as opposed to "breadth + depth" or "broad + deep" which just does not look good to me.

I am not, however, a **native speaker** so I would like one **to come forth and clarify** if I am maybe missing something here and the image does "sound about right" after all? Maybe I'm just looking at this from pure grammar standpoint and miss some intricate wordplay?

Comment: I agree: it should be "*breadth & depth*" or "*broad + deep*".

Comment: It's a "helpful" translation from Polish. The author apparently has tried what best could be used. It's not correct, though it serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't fit, for me. My immediate assumption is that this has been prepared by somebody whose English is not very strong.

Comment: Thank you, my thoughts exactly. Will wait a little longer to see if there are other inputs before marking you answer as accepted!